# Pitching an idea to executives

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, management, software-development

So I work as a developer for this company. I have an idea to develop a new system for the company where I would own 10% and they would own 90% of the system. The system would integrate with their existing systems, they would sell it to existing clients, and I would develop it for free after my normal work hours.

My question is how do I propose this idea to the executives that work on the same floor as me without putting my job at risk? I have my concerns listed below

1. "I would own 10%" me asking this could look like I'm trying to compete against the company or something
2. I am a junior developer for them to leave the building of an entire system completely up to me seems risky

What is the likelihood that the company would be open to something like this? After all they wouldn't be putting much at risk by not paying for development costs and if the system turns out to be a hit they cash in on 90% without really doing anything.

I am very passionate about the system and I believe that it would be a huge success. I don't want to loose my job though.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere why? Can you explain in more detail I am new to the industry

Comment: It is called intellectual capital. When I worked for IBM they owned any idea I came up with. The only way for me to pursue the idea in my "off" time would have been to get an explicit waiver from them. This was explicitly to avoid the scenario "But I didn't solve this problem at work. The solution came to me while I was taking a shower at home."

Comment: @MaxW I presented this software to 3 of their employees one high level during my interview

Comment: @the1.8gpaProgammer so are you actually a salaried worker on that company?

Comment: @the1.8gpaProgammer I think your assumption about their risk is wrong. If you work in your spare time the risk is you are exhausting yourself and thus less productive in your work time or even might burn out. And as a side note, if they'd really get behind the idea of building some system, they'd probably want to put it through their usual processes and planning to deal with any risk.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is how do I propose this idea to the executives that work on the same floor as me without putting my job at risk?

I really doubt that you **job** will be at risk here. What *could* be at risk is your idea.

You are currently working for that company, so given this condition I would not recommend doing such thing (at least not while hired by that company).

They could well put you develop an app like this as your regular tasks, if somehow they decided to build such system on their own.

> What is the likelihood that the company would be open to something like this?

Can't really tell, only knowing them could give a hint on that likelihood, and it would still be guessing. Depends on every company and the kind of individuals involved.

**However**, this approach could make more sense if you were proposing it as a *freelancer* outside contractor, etc., where you can actually negotiate on the project and are not subject to any **intellectual or technical contracts or restrictions that most companies have** on their employees.

You can surely proceed further if you wish, and put this project idea you have on the table for consideration. Just remember that it is still *their table* we are talking about here.

*Bonus:* remember to check your contract, NDA's, etc., thoroughly before doing anything, so you know the grounds you are stepping on.